# IDENTITY SEED is incrementing based on other tables seed values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I'm using SQL SERVER 2017 and using SSMS. I have created a few tables whose Primary Key is **int** and enabled **Is Identity** and set **Identity Increment = 1 and Identity Seed=1** For all the tables I have used the same method. But When I added one record in a table say **Lead** it's **ID** was **2**, Then added value to the table say **Followup** then its **ID** was **3**.
Here I'm adding the screenshots for a better understanding

Lead Table
[image: Lead Table]

Followup Table
[image: Followup Table]

Is there any option available to avoid this? can we keep the identity individual for each table?

Comment: If you care about the actual numerical values assigned to identity columns, sooner or later you'll come unstuck. If you treat them as *opaque identifiers* that happen to fit into numerical columns, you'll tend to be okay.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you for your response. Is Identity is working like this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15) is quite specific about what `identity` **does not guarantee**:

> The identity property on a column does not guarantee the following:
>
> - **Uniqueness of the value** . . .
> - **Consecutive values within a transaction** . . .
> - **Consecutive values after server restart or other failures** . . .
> - **Reuse of values**

In general, the "uniqueness" property is a non-issue, because identity columns are usually the primary key (or routinely declared at least `unique`), which does guarantee uniqueness.

The purpose of an `identity` column is to provide a unique numeric identifier different from other rows, so it can be readily used as a primary key.  There are no other guarantees.  And for performance SQL Server has lots of short-cuts that result in gaps.

If you want no gaps, then the simplest way is to assign a value when querying:

```
row_number() over (order by <identity column>)
```

That is not 100% satisfying, because deletions can affect the value.  I also think that on parallel systems, inserts can as well (because identities might be cached on individual nodes).

If you do not care about performance, you can use a `sequence` for assigning a value.  This is less performant than using an `identity`.  Basically, it requires serializing all the inserts to guarantee the properties of the insert.

I should note that even with a sequence, a failed insert can still produce gaps, so it still might not do what you want.